# React native whne i type : yarn ios ExpoModulesCore/ExpoModulesCore.modulemap' not found

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am using mac Big Sur version 11.6 and i am stuck on this problem

Debug-iphoneos/ExpoModulesCore/ExpoModulesCore.modulemap' not found
Failed to build iOS project. "xcodebuild" exited with error code 65.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible that pod install failed.

1. Copy the contents of your Podfile somewhere safe
2. Run: pod cache clean --all
3. Remove "Podfile"-file from the dir.
4. Xcode: Product > Clean Build Folder
5. Run: pod init. A new "Podfile"-file is added to the dir
6. Start adding parts of your original Podfile to this file
7. Run: pod install
8. Try to build your project again